# Creating child records with django-mptt

Tags: django-mptt

I have successfully completed the django-mptt tutorial. What I cannot figure out how to do is create a child of a child.

By child of a child, i mean a third level deep and more. See example below, I want to create 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.1.1

```
1.0 Product Z
      1.1 Product A
      1.2 Product B
      1.3 Product P
            1.3.1 Product X
                   1.3.1.1 Product O
            1.3.2 Product Y
2.0 Product H
```

In the [doco](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#insert-node-node-target-position-last-child-save-false) i found `insert_node` but dont understand it enough to get it working. Also i found something in the [code comments](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/managers.py) (line 317) regarding `insert_node` that says:

```
NOTE: This is a low-level method; it does NOT respect ``MPTTMeta.order_insertion_by``.
        In most cases you should just set the node's parent and let mptt call this during save.
```

Should i be using 'insert_node' or is there a better way? If 'insert_node' should be used, then can you provide an example of its use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a little confusing, I admit. But as you can read [here](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#model-options), the `order_insertion_by` field should only be used, when you're after something like a standard insertion behavior, for example alphabetically ordered trees and so on as it triggers an extra db query.

However, if you want to insert a node at a specific point in your tree, you have to use either
[`TreeManager.insert_node`](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#insert-node-node-target-position-last-child-save-false) or [`MPTTModel.insert_at`](http://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#insert-at-target-position-first-child-save-false), the latter being a convenience method for calling the first.

So, according to your example, this leads to the following three options to add a new *1.3.3 Product Q* as last child of *1.3 Product P*:

```
new_node = ProductNode(name='1.3.3 Product Q')

parent = ProductNode.objects.get(name='1.3 Product P')


# With `order_insertion_by`

new_node.parent = parent
new_node.save()


# With `TreeManager.insert_node`

ProductNode.objects.insert_node(new_node, parent, position='last-child', save=True)


# With `MPTTModel.insert_at`

new_node.insert_at(parent, position='last-child', save=True)
```